# Is there another way instead of pagination to fetch data from api to a list view in parts using flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, pagination

This is my query_Model

```
Future fetchDataa(String url, String sortOrder,
  {Map<String, dynamic> parameters, bool fromCash = false}) async {
if (await canLoadData() && !fromCash) {
  return fetchDataFromServer(url, parameters: {});
} else {
  startLoading();
  return fechDataFromCache(url, sortOrder);
}
```

}

Future fetchDataFromServer(String url, String page , {Map<String, dynamic> parameters}) async {
DioCacheManager _dioCacheManager;
_dioCacheManager = DioCacheManager(CacheConfig());

```
Options _cacheOptions = buildCacheOptions(Duration(hours: 1) , forceRefresh: true);
_dio.interceptors.add(_dioCacheManager.interceptor);
try {
  final response = await _dio.get(
      url,
      queryParameters: parameters,
      options: _cacheOptions);
  if (!url.contains('page')) items.clear();
  if (errors.isNotEmpty) errors.clear();
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    saveLocalData(url, response.data);
    finishLoading();
    return response.data;
  } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
    if (response.data['error']["massage"] == "Unauthorized") appModel.setApplicationSavedInformation('token', '');
    receivedError();
    errors = response.data['error'];
    return errors;
  } else {
    receivedError();
    throw Exception('Authentication Error');
  }
} on DioError catch (exception) {
  if (exception == null || exception.toString().contains('SocketException')) {
    throw Exception("Network Error");
  } else if (exception.type == DioErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT || exception.type == DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT) {
    throw Exception("Could'nt connect, please ensure you have a stable network.");
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

DataTable or PaginatedDataTable widgets in flutter used to display a list fetch from api...

You can use any one to show your data...

PaginatedDataTable widgets having inbuilt pagination property you can just use those property to construct...

Comment: I tried to understand how to compile this widget with my code but I could not so              Could you please try to explain it with this code that shows in the question?